# How to add Header values to HttpWebRequest in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am developing simple Http client to consume an Asp.Net Core Web API. I want to pass few http header values to the Web API via HttpHeaderCollection. In previous versions of .Net framework allowed to add header values to the HttpHeaderCollection as following

```
WebHeaderCollection aPIHeaderValues = new    WebHeaderCollection();           
aPIHeaderValues .Add("UserName","somevalue");
aPIHeaderValues .Add("TokenValue", "somevalue");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.add(aPIHeaderValues);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse();
```

But in .Net Core there is no way to add headers to **request.Headers** collection. As well as we cannot add headers by defining new WebHeaderCollection

```
WebHeaderCollection aPIHeaderValues = new    WebHeaderCollection();
```

Is there any alternative way to do this in .Net Core

Answer (score 12):

The question is about `HttpWebRequest`, which is different than `HttpClient`.
Using `HttpWebRequest`, you simply assign to a header you want like this:

```
request.Headers["HeaderToken"] = "HeaderValue";
```

.NET core will create the header if it does not exist.

Comment: Please don't add taglines to your posts. The place for those is in your user profile.

Comment: I think the question is about `HttpClient` and not `HttpWebRequest`. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494919/593985) from @fabricio-koch is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example:

```
SampleClass sampleClass= null;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()){
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "TOKEN");
    var data = await client.GetAsync("MY_API_URL");
    var jsonResponse = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (jsonResponse != null)
        sampleClass= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(jsonResponse);
    return sampleClass;
}
```

Comment: This will only work for default request headers. It will not work for custom headers.